# Nginx 301 redirect syntax error

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I just found that my nginx syntax was not correct:

```
location /news { rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog redirect;}
```

I want to redirect mysite.com/news to mysite.com/blog but that code was redirecting more pages to blog.

Anyone can help me explaining the error and tell me how to correctly redirect?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be to still use a `location`.  If you don't want anything below `/news` to redirect to `/blog` (e.g., no need for a wildcard), then the following is what you want, and is probably the most efficient way to create a single alias:

```
location = /news {
    return 301 /blog;
}
```

Otherwise, if you do, in fact, want a wildcard:

```
location /news {
    rewrite ^/news(.*)  /blog$1 permanent;
}
```

P.S. Also note that [`redirect` would cause `302` redirects; if you want `301`, then the keyword is called `permanent`](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_rewrite_module.c#ngx_http_rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put it inside the location block. Just a single rewrite rule is enough.

`rewrite ^/news/?$ /blog redirect;`